# Question related to articles when using with main, major, and key

Tags: articles

When I see the phrase 'The main advantage of something', I know the speakers imply that there is only one advantage. However, in the two following phrases 'a key advantage of something', and 'a major advantage of something, why is the article 'a' used instead of 'the' in this case? I think 'main', 'key', and 'major' somehow indicate the uniqueness of something. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you include context and any research you have performed?

Comment: The main advantage of living in the countryside...; a major advantage of living in cities...; a key advantage of taking the subway... I checked Google Ngram and saw that 'a major advantage of ...', and 'a key advantage of ...' are more common; as for 'the main advantage of ...', it is predominantly common. I am doing research on autonomous vehicles.

Comment: Main advantage does not imply there is only one advantage - it implies that there is at least two - the main advantage and at least one other. **Main** always indicates one of several.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speaker uses 'the' to indicate that there is only one key thing. In my opinion, the speaker indicates that there could be more than one key thing by using the indefinite article 'a',and he is talking about one of those key advantages.

Answer (score 0):

> Main = larger, more important, or having more influence than others of the same type
>
> [Cambridge dictionary[(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/main)

From this (relevant to your quotation) definition, we see *main* is a comparative. To refer to the main advantage tells is that there are one or more other, lesser advantages. The main advantage is therefore uniquely defined and attracts the definite article “the”.

A major advantage or a key advantage is one of several advantages and attracts the indefinite article “a”.

Consider:

**The** main English vowel is E. {it is the unique one, used more than the others}

**A** key English letter is E. {it is one of several key letters}

**A** major English letter is E. {like some other letters, it is used a lot and is an important vowel